# How to password protect entire excel file in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, openxlsx

I have a dataframes that has already passed to a list below

```
P.attached_all<-list("Airtime and Data" = P_Airtime_Data,
                           "Cable TV" = P_cable,
                           "Electricity" = P_Electricity,
                           "Betting" = P_betting,
                           "Pin" = P_Pin)
```

What I want to do is password-protect the entire file in such a way that when the users click and download then open the file it will first prompt them to input the password.

I have tried this method below
library(XLConnect)

```
# load but do not attach the write.xlsx() function from the xlsx package ----
xlsx::write.xlsx(x = mtcars, file = "mtcars.xlsx", password = "1234_fghj")
```

going buy the example that was shared online, i came up with my own

```
xlsx::write.xlsx(x = attached_all, file = "mtcars.xlsx", password = "1234_fghj")
```

i get this error below.

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 59977, 0
```

Is the any solution or any package that do this job better, i really need help
Thanks

Comment: I don’t see any dplyr or tidyverse content here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`wb_protect()`](https://janmarvin.github.io/openxlsx2/reference/wb_protect.html) if you just want the prompt

```r
library(openxlsx2)
wb <- wb_workbook()
wb$add_worksheet("S1")

wb <- wb_protect(
  wb,
  protect = TRUE,
  password = "Password",
  lock_structure = TRUE,
  type = 2L,
  file_sharing = TRUE,
  username = "Test",
  read_only_recommended = TRUE
)
```

If you want file level encryption have a look at [msoc](https://github.com/JanMarvin/msoc).